# Eigenvalues of an operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

I have just started working with operators, ie objects that map functions to other functions, and I have heard people talking about the eigenavalues of an operator that can be obtained through spectral analysis.

Every text I read on this area deals with it abstractly. I would like to observe an example so that I can "see with my own" eyes that operators have eigenvalues. Eg. when people start linear algebra they work with realized examples of matrices that use real numbers rather just dealing with variables representing matrix indices.

In the case of 2x2 matrices if we take the matrix with a $2$ and a $1$ on the diagonal well this clearly has an eigenvalue of $2$ which means anything on the x-axis gets scaled by two.

Is there an analagous example for operators? Where we can take some function, which has infinite dimensions, and have an eigenvalue that multiplies one of these dimensions (or would it need to be a 'range of dimensions') by 2?

What would such an operator an its eigenfunctions look like?

Comment: see yourself https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory#Sturm.E2.80.93Liouville_equations_as_self-adjoint_differential_operators or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation#Vibrating_membrane

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The derivative operator $D=\frac d{dx}$ has eigenfunctions $e^{cx}$ with eigenvalue $c$

Answer (score 2):

In a sense your $2\times2$ matrix is already an example. A matrix is an operator mapping operators (again $2\times2$ matrices) onto other such operators. Eigenfunctions would be the matrices consisting of the eigenvectors. Other examples are the sin/cos waves $sin(\omega t - kx)$ as eigenfunctions of the d'Alembert operator.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]$. Let $Lf = \frac{1}{i}\frac{df}{dx}$ be defined on the domain $\mathcal{D}(L)$ consisting of all absolutely continuous functions $f$ for which $f' \in L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]$ and $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$. Then $L$ has eigenfunctions $e^{inx}$. That is
$$
                  Le^{inx} = ne^{inx},\;\;\; n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\cdots.
$$
Furthermore, this is a complete orthonormal basis with respect to the inner product
$$
                (f,g) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt.
$$
The operator $L$ is "diagonalized" with respect to this basis.

Serious eigenfunction and eigenvalue analysis really started with differential operators on infinite-dimensional spaces, and trickled down to the matrix level. This is the opposite of what you would naturally believe to be the case. Eigenfunction equations came naturally out of Fourier's separation of variables technique that he devised to solve Partial Differential Equations. The values of separation parameters had to be found, along with their corresponding differential equation solutions; such problems are now considered to be eigenvalue and eigenfunction (or eigenvector) problems.

Answer (score 1):

Take a rectangle $[0,1]\times [0,\pi]$. Then the eigenvalues of the second derivative on $[0,1]$ with Neumann b.c. are $\{-\pi^2 n^2:n\in \mathbb N\}$,  the eigenvalues of the second derivative on $[0,\pi]$ with Neumann b.c. are $\{- m^2:m\in \mathbb N\}$, and the eigenvalues of the Laplacian on the rectangle are $\{-\pi^2 n^2-m^2:n,m\in \mathbb N\}$. So like in your example you can scale in one direction while holding the other one.